# Finding probability density function of a bounded region in $xy$-plane

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

Let $A$ be the region in the $xy$-plane  bounded by the parabola $x = -y^2$ and the line $y = x + 2$. An experiment consists of choosing a point uniformly at random from the region A. My attempt is to find the probability density function of the bounded region. I have find the range of X is from -4 to -1. How do I attempt to find the probability mass function using calculus?

Answer (score 0):

$$p(x,y) = \frac{3}{40} \quad {\rm if} \quad y-2 \leq x \leq y^2$$

and $0$ otherwise.

[image]

Comment: How you get $p(x,y) =3/40$? Is this number the area bounded by the region?